# Nonblocking IIS Express startups

Tags: powershell

I can start Cassini in a batch file like so:

```
start "" /B "%common%\microsoft shared\DevServer\11.0\WebDev.WebServer40.exe" /port:%port% /path:"%~dp0%svcDir%"
```

This starts without blocking the command line.  Can I start IISExpress without blocking the command line?  I tried saving the following command in `startiis.ps1`:

```
start-process "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe" /config:%userprofile%\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config /CompanyName.ProjectName.api -windowstyle Hidden
```

When I run `& ".\startiis.ps1"` I receive error:

> Start-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts
>   argument '/CompanyName.ProjectName.api'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things about your approach...

1. Calling environment variables in PowerShell uses the provider `$env`
2. If you are going to use `Start-Process` you need to separate your command and your arguments

---

```
start-process "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe" -ArgumentList "/config:$($env:USERPROFILE)\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config /CompanyName.ProjectName.api" -WindowStyle Hidden
```

[`Start-Process`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849848.aspx) was throwing an error since it does not have a 3rd positional parameters.  In your example the breakdown was that "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe" occupied the `-FilePath` and "/config:%userprofile%\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config" took the position for `-ArgumentList`. You wanted all of those pieces to be arguments.

You did not have to specify `-ArgumentList`. Quoting the all the arguments as a string would have sufficed.

You could also use the call operator to execute in place if you dont need the other features of `Start-Process`. It's a good practice to quote the arguments to ensure they are parsed correctly.

```
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe" "/config:$($env:USERPROFILE)\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config" "/CompanyName.ProjectName.api"
```